# XML Parsing with Children()

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to parse the following xml https://ota.cartrawler.com/cartrawlerota/files/static/ctlocation.EN.xml

I need to parse locations based on countries, this is what I have:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("ctlocation.ES.xml") 
   or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$name3 = $_GET["nombre"];
foreach($xml->Country->children('Albania') as $loca){
    $name2 = $loca[0]['Name'];
    echo $name2;
    echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

It's not retuning any error but it's not parsing anything either.
Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what happens if you var_dump($loca) in that foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observation #1:**

If you have performance problems due to the large size (~35M) of  `ctlocation.ES.xml`, consider using [XmlStreamer](https://github.com/prewk/XmlStreamer) for parsing large XML files in PHP.

**Observation #2:**

Aside from the size of the input XML, there are correctness issues with the PHP you posted.
There is no root level `Country` element in `ctlocation.ES.xml`, and 'Albania' only exists as a `@name` attribute on a `/CTLocations/Country` element.  Also, you have to account for the namespace in which your input XML elements exist.

*Let's use a small sample from the input XML and load it as a string so as to create a small, self-contained example.*

**To step through the locations of Albania, try this:**

```
<?php 
$xmlstring = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CTLocations xmlns="http://www.cartrawler.com/">
  <Country code="AL" name="Albania" continent="Europe">
    <Location Id="7188" Name="Tirana Airport" Lat="41.42108838" Lng="19.71271276" CountryCode="AL" Address="Tirana Airport Muhamet Gjollesha Str., Muhamet Gjollesha Str., Tirana" CityName="Tirana" Airport="1" AirportCode="TIA" RailwayStation="0"/>
    <Location Id="30768" Name="Tirana Downtown" Lat="41.332" Lng="19.832" CountryCode="AL" Address="Rruga E Durresit. Nr 61, Tirana" CityName="Tirana" Airport="0" RailwayStation="0"/>
    <Location Id="52400" Name="Sheraton Italia Square" Lat="0.0" Lng="0.0" CountryCode="AL" Address="Square Italia Hotel Sheraton , Tirana," CityName="Tirana" PostalCode="" Airport="0" RailwayStation="0"/>
  </Country>
  <Country code="AD" name="Andorra" continent="Europe">
    <Location Id="4650" Name="Escaldes" Lat="42.511" Lng="1.548" CountryCode="AD" Address="Avda. Miquel Mateu, 25, Escaldes-engordany , Andorra, Ad700" CityName="Andorra" PostalCode="AD700" Airport="0" RailwayStation="0"/>
    <Location Id="152576" Name="Andorra" Lat="42.508" Lng="1.522" CountryCode="AD" Address="Avda D Enclar, 142, Edifici Becier, Andorra La Vella, Ad500" CityName="Andorra La Vella" PostalCode="AD500" Airport="0" RailwayStation="0"/>
  </Country>
</CTLocations>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring)
   or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ct', 'http://www.cartrawler.com/');
echo "The locations in Albania:<br/>";
foreach($xml->xpath("/ct:CTLocations/ct:Country[@name='Albania']/ct:Location") as $loca) {
    echo $loca['Name'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
echo "Done."
?>
```

**The above script will yield this output:**

```
The locations in Albania:
Tirana Airport
Tirana Downtown
Sheraton Italia Square
Done.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! spent the whole day trying to figure this out! You're awesome